# Tool for repackaging library from windows lib with embarcadero tlib?

Tags: delphi, audio, lib

I've bought a wonderful audio library from CricketTechnology with source. I cannot dump ck.lib with tDump64 and also tLib64 doesn't work for me. But windows LIB lists the content of ck.lib and can probably extract the .obj files. My idea is to extract all the .obj files listed and to repackage them with tLib. Is there a tool? I want to use the wonderful library with Delphi and have added some functions to the source code that are free from C++-objects.

Comment: I don't know the lib, but If you want to use C++ objects, then be sure to read my article on how to do this: [*Using C++ objects in Delphi*](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html). If you already have a DLL instead of a lib, see if you can use that. Also check with tdump.exe and tlib.exe instead of tdump64.exe and tlib64.exe.

Comment: I just looked at the API: C++ interface but no plain C interface (which is, IMO, not well thought out). So you will really have to do what I write in my article. I would personally just flatten the code. Also read my [*Using C object files in Delphi*](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html). You may be lucky and be able to link to the object files directly, in Win64. Not so easy in Win32.

Comment: You can't ask for tool recommendations here according to the [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You may be able to ask at [softwarerecs.se]  instead, but be sure to read that site's guidelines first, as they're somewhat strict about what they allow.

Comment: You might want to rephrase the question to not to mention the word "tool", otherwise it will most likely be closed within a few hours.

Comment: I don't think it is will be possible to convert the lib files, because the obj files it includes might also be incompatible with Delphi.